#N/A Result in VLOOKUP
Using a VLOOKUP function With a workbook and multiple sheets, Google Sheets keep responding with an "#N/A", even though I am using a valid VLOOKUP.
The source sheet (Sheet1) is dynamically driven (synced to a WordPress plugin that posts the data dynamically when someone sends a form). The target sheet (Grade 4) is where the formula resides but isn't working.
WHAT IS SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN:
"Grade 4" sheet is supposed to populate with data based upon the reference number in B1. That number is searched in "Sheet 1" data range A2:I9 and should return the value from "Sheet 1" column 1. It does not.


I have checked the following:

the data is correct
the reference is correct
the data range is fine
the CELL format matches between the reference and the requested index value in the data range (doesn't matter if I use the "TEXT" function within my VLOOKUP--same result).
there are no excess spaces in the cells

Thank you for the help!

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

SUGGESTION
The reason why you are getting an error with your VLOOKUP function is because the search key is only being used to search on the first column of your defined range, as mentioned in the official documentation:

This is the value you search in the first column of the range. If you expect a non-error value, the search key must be in the first column of the range. Cell reference is also supported.

Currently, there is no parameter in the VLOOKUP function to perform a search on a defined column; as such, you can instead use the XLOOKUP function. You can use this formula:
=XLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!C2:C$9,Sheet1!A2:A$9)

Using the XLOOKUP function allows you to define a specific range where you want your defined search key to be scanned through, and return its matching value from a separate column range.
One thing to point out is that XLOOKUP only returns one value, and based on your provided screenshots, here are some alternative formulas that you can use to pull multiple data based off your search key:
a) Using FILTER function
=arrayformula(SPLIT(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!C2:C=B1)," "))

b) Using QUERY function
=arrayformula(SPLIT(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C9, "select A where C contains '"&B1&"' ",0), " "))

Both formulas will be able to pull all of the data from your database that satisfies the defined search key. I've also added the SPLIT function with it to split the names to their first and last names, respectively.
OUTPUT


Let me know if this answers your question, and if you have any questions or inquiries, feel free to reply to this so that we can discuss further.

Hello, and thank you for these great examples, @Mic Test. It took me a bit to understand the technique. Once I figured out the formulas you send, my dynamic data is now filtering like a charm!
Thank you very much for the help! Everything is working great!

You're welcome! Glad to know that it's working well for you.
